# WooCommerce Database Errors

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an error that it being reported in the back end of my Wordpress/WooCommerce install. I have virtually no experience of SQL so I'm at a bit of a loss as to where to start addressing the issue.

Specifically, I have a plugin called Query Monitor that is alerting that certain pages in the back end are producing a DB error.  The most problematic of these is the Edit Product screen that shows a repeating error.  The error is reported as follows:

**Query**

```
SELECT postmeta.post_id AS product_id 
FROM wp_postmeta AS postmeta 
LEFT JOIN wp_posts AS products
ON ( products.ID = postmeta.post_id ) 
WHERE postmeta.meta_key LIKE 'attribute_%' 
AND postmeta.meta_value = 'uk-10' 
AND products.post_parent =
```

**Call Stack**

```
display_price_in_variation_option_name()
apply_filters('woocommerce_variation_option_name')
WC_Meta_Box_Product_Data::output_variations()
WC_Meta_Box_Product_Data::output()
do_meta_boxes()
```

**Component**

```
Plugin: woocommerce
```

**Error**

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server 
version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6
```

Is this a problem in one of my theme files or do I need to look closer at the DB?

Any help very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have missed value for where,(last one)

```
WHERE postmeta.meta_key LIKE 'attribute_%' 
AND postmeta.meta_value = 'uk-10' 
AND products.post_parent = ""
                            ^// here
```

Comment: Thanks - that makes complete sense.  Where will that bit of code be located?  In one of the template files I assume?

Comment: im not from wordpress background. just saw the mysql error and spotted the error.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll have a look to see where that code is being pulled from :)